# Why does my image leave the container elsewhere than Firefox?

Tags: html, css

(*this is my first experience with stackoverflow, apologies if it's not appropriate somehow.*)

I've taken the piece of code with the issue and recreated it in jsfiddle (*also my first experience with that*)

also here's a link to my GitHub (*new here too*) where the problem is located.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/patmilton/n253v48o/1/
GitHub: https://patmilton.github.io/CCbyMe/cc02.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cc02.css">
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="icon-container">
        <div id="bicon"><img src="image"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
.icon-container {
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

#bicon {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

#bicon:hover {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: I'm just reviewing first posts, while I can't answer your questions, I like very much that you have added the code, and a fiddle to demo it. Good start!

Comment: @Tim Appreciated! I tried my best, and luckily I got an answer really quickly, so don't worry about not having an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the parameter `max-width: 100%` for image. This is because the picture is larger than the block in which it is located.

```css
#bicon img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: ah thanks! I thought it was fine to do it at the id-level, seems to work now.

Comment: @PatMilton It is always best to specify this explicitly for the image, for example, declare it over the entire scope: `img { max-width: 100%; }`

Comment: Appreciated, I'll do that from now on, seems simple. I guess maybe Firefox does it automatically since it worked fine there.